# how to select the content with sed in linux shell

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed

In my project, I have a linux file: audit_check.log

The content of audit_check.log is like:

```
2019-01-08 15:09:32,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3111  sh keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:09:40,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3112  cat /tmp/keycmdtmp.log ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:10:30,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3115  cat /var/log/audit_check.log,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:10:51,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3116  echo yang > xie,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:10:54,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3117  rm -rf xie,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:10:56,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3118  sh keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:11:35,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3119  vi keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:11:39,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3120  sh keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:11:39,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 15:09 ,root,vm1, 3120  rm keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:12:39,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3120  rm keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
```

Now, I want to select all lines in the same minute.

for example, when timestr is:

```
2019-01-08 15:09
```

the correct result should be:

```
2019-01-08 15:09:32,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3111  sh keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:09:40,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3112  cat /tmp/keycmdtmp.log ,/root/USER_CD
```

But the line:

```
2019-01-08 15:11:39,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 15:09 ,root,vm1, 3120  rm keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
```

is exclude in result.

I have tried:

```
timestr=`date +%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M`

 sed -n '/^$timestr/p' /var/log/audit_check.log  > /tmp/keycmdtmp.log
```

but /tmp/keycmdtmp.log is empty. When i remove "^" like:

```
timestr=`date +%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M`

sed -n '/$timestr/p' /var/log/audit_check.log  > /tmp/keycmdtmp.log
```

the result is changed to :

```
2019-01-08 15:09:32,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3111  sh keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:09:40,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3112  cat /tmp/keycmdtmp.log ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:11:39,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 15:09 ,root,vm1, 3120  rm keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD

It seems nothing wrong, who can help me?
```

Comment: [Quoting](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) [Quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

Answer (score 5):

This is better suited for `awk`:

```
awk -F, -v dt="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')" '$1 ~ dt' file
```

```
2019-01-08 15:09:32,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3111  sh keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:09:40,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3112  cat /tmp/keycmdtmp.log ,/root/USER_CD
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `grep` if you only need to filter the input lines that match your time constraint (no need to go for `awk` or `sed`).

**INPUT:**

```
$ cat dates_test.in
2019-01-08 15:09:32,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3111  sh keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:09:40,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3112  cat /tmp/keycmdtmp.log ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:10:30,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3115  cat /var/log/audit_check.log,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:10:51,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3116  echo yang > xie,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:10:54,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3117  rm -rf xie,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:10:56,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3118  sh keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:11:35,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3119  vi keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:11:39,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3120  sh keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 17:20:39,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 15:09 ,root,vm1, 3120  rm keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 17:20:39,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3120  rm keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
```

**COMMAND:**

```
grep "^`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'`" dates_test.in
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$ grep "^`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'`" dates_test.in 
2019-01-08 17:20:39,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 15:09 ,root,vm1, 3120  rm keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 17:20:39,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3120  rm keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
```

Answer (score 0):

Try double quotes:

```
sed -n "/^$timestr/p" file
```

Like this:

```
$ cat test.log
2019-01-08 15:09:32,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3111  sh keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:09:40,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3112  cat /tmp/keycmdtmp.log ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:10:30,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3115  cat /var/log/audit_check.log,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:10:51,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3116  echo yang > xie,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:10:54,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3117  rm -rf xie,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:10:56,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3118  sh keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:11:35,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3119  vi keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:11:39,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3120  sh keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:11:39,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 15:09 ,root,vm1, 3120  rm keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:12:39,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3120  rm keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD

$ echo $timestr
2019-01-08 15:09

$ sed -n "/^$timestr/p" test.log
2019-01-08 15:09:32,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3111  sh keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:09:40,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3112  cat /tmp/keycmdtmp.log ,/root/USER_CD
```

By `awk`, if you already have `$timestr`:

```
$ awk -v str="$timestr" '$0~"^"str' test.log
2019-01-08 15:09:32,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3111  sh keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:09:40,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3112  cat /tmp/keycmdtmp.log ,/root/USER_CD
```

Just for fun, another way to invoke the variable:

```
$ x="$timestr" awk '$0~"^"ENVIRON["x"]' test.log
2019-01-08 15:09:32,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3111  sh keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:09:40,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3112  cat /tmp/keycmdtmp.log ,/root/USER_CD
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your logs you can try to add comma to the sed like this:

```
sed -n "/${timestr}\,/p" /var/log/audit_check.log  > /tmp/keycmdtmp.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that %F represents the date in ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD), so you could write it as below to further shorten it.

```
$ grep "^`date '+%F 15:09'`" dates_test.in
2019-01-08 15:09:32,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3111  sh keycmd.sh ,/root/USER_CD
2019-01-08 15:09:40,root     pts/0        2019-01-08 11:30 ,root,vm1, 3112  cat /tmp/keycmdtmp.log ,/root/USER_CD
```